# Join results from two selects - mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have two select queries:

```
SELECT Name as CategoryName FROM providerscategories where ID in(
Select catId from provider_in_category 
where providerUsername = 'a' group by providerUsername
);
```

and the other one is:

```
SELECT Username, providerName from serviceproviders where Username in(
SELECT providerUsername from usedproviders where Username='Admin')
```

Basically what it does is getting the providerName from the usedProviders by Username from usedproviders table, then gets the UserName and the providerName of the provider based on the results.
Then I want to check which category this provider is in and get this category name, and add it to the UserName and the providerName of the category.

Here is a sql fiddle link: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b37/9)

the desired result set is:

> Username | ProviderName | categoryName

Comment: Sorry, but this is all awful. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: updated my post, added a sql Fiddle link

Answer (score 1):

OK. Let's start here... what part of the problem does the following query not solve...

```
SELECT sp.*
     , up.username
     , c.name
     , pc.catid
  FROM usedproviders up
  JOIN serviceproviders sp
    ON sp.username = up.providerusername
  JOIN provider_in_category pc
    ON pc.providerusername = up.providerusername
  JOIN providerscategories c
    ON c.id = pc.catid
 WHERE up.username = 'Admin';
+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+-------+
| Username | providerName | username | name         | catid |
+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+-------+
| a        | providerA    | Admin    | CategoryName |     1 |
| b        | providerB    | Admin    | CategoryName |     1 |
+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: Where do I specify the Username I want to make the search on (aka 'Admin')

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do

```
select 
sp.Username,
sp.providerName,
Name
from serviceproviders sp 
left join
(
  select
  usedproviders.ProviderUsername ,
  providerscategories.Name
  from 
  provider_in_category pic
  inner join 
  usedproviders on usedproviders.ProviderUsername = pic.providerUsername
  inner join 
  providerscategories on providerscategories.ID = pic.catId
  where 
  usedproviders.ProviderUsername = 'a'
  AND usedproviders.Username = 'admin'
  group by usedproviders.ProviderUsername
)t
on sp.Username = t.ProviderUsername
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b37/38)**

I have seen you are filtering data with `admin` and `a` so if you dont want to see the 2nd record NULL then instead LEFTJOIN just make it INNER join the first part.

Also if you do not want filter then remove the where clause and will list all data.

something as **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b37/43)**

Comment: Admin is a param I will put in code, 'a' is just a sample as I want to get the Provider usernames from the first query